# Android:Screen Off and Lock Notfication?

Tags: android

I want to continue running my application when the backlight and screen goes off and lock. How do i find out whether the device screen goes off and lock from my application through notification so that i can ignore it and continue running my app.?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Android is an app, including Home and Lock screen. So your app is not running unless you have a background service. Even that can be interrupted at any time and you should not try to prevent system from doing so. It has to do with tight memory management in the Android phone. Mark Murphy wrote [excellent article](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/) on that topic you can read at this link

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a broadcast receiver that will relaunch your main activity when it receives screen on or off actions.

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

You can then just create a simple receiver to launch your desired activity.
Also, you'll need to make sure your activity can override the screen off, and lock.
You can do that with this code;

```
final Window win = getWindow();
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: does not work. you can only listen to those broadcasts from a receiver registered in your activity.